# How to get ErrorText to display

Tags: winforms, validation, datagridview

I am making a new DataGridView with some cells that can be edited. I have a CellValidating event handler, in which I set the ErrorText of the row and cell, but no text or icon is showing up anywhere in the window.

I have looked for and followed many other issues like this, but nobody else's solution has worked for me yet

- Made sure that ShowCellErrors & ShowRowErrors = true
- Set DGV.RowTemplate.Height to be > 19
- Made sure that DGV.AutoSizeRowsMode was not set to anything
- Set ShowToolTips = false
- Even tried *not* doing `e.Cancel = true` in the CellValidating handler

So what else is there that might block row and/or cell ErrorText from appearing on the screen?

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28d812bb-5f33-46d6-94dd-6a2d1f442a29/displaying-errortext-on-the-current-cell-in-datagridview-control?forum=vblanguage) will help.

Comment: I have considered that, as a last resort. But all the MSDN documentation I've read just treats ErrorText (row or cell) like something that simply displays...though it doesn't spell out *where*, or how. It doesn't make sense to me that a standard DataGridView feature like ErrorText should require a hack to get it to display to the user. There should be some *normal* way to just get the darn error text and/or icon to appear!